# How to access the app's "in-time" icon in flutter(dart code)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to display the app's icon in my flutter app
I have an app with many icons since I use flutter_launcher_icons

research with google and stackoverflow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already have set launcher icon if yes then now you can use Use https://pub.dev/packages/application_icon

```
import 'package:application_icon/application_icon.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          // use AppIcon to show your application icon
          child: AppIconImage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or directly access launcher icon from asset folder